# Output value in javascript from php loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not sure how to search this, but I have an array in php numbered 1 to 20. I have a foreach loop to output the values and have the user be able to click on the numbers. After clicking the number, the page would then output the number clicked.

HTML:

```
<div id="chapters" onclick="getChapter()">
    $array = range(1,20);
    foreach($array as $chapter) {
    ?>
        <p class="getChapter" id="currChapter">Chapter <?php echo $chapter;?></p>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function getChapter() {
    chapter = document.getElementById("currChapter").id;
    document.write(chapter);
}
```

I'm not able to output the number that the user clicks on.

I have tried putting

```
 id=<?php $chapter?>
```

, but that does not work as well as replacing id with value and name.

Comment: And what is the problem? Also, how many elements with the same `id` you think `getElementById` might find?

Comment: It would get all 20 I think. But i've tried not using id and that still would not work. Am I suppose to use something other than <p>?

Comment: How is that? Please don't guess, read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Also, _don't use_ [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write).

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write()` in code that runs after the page has been loaded. It will replace everything on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend passing the $chapter as parameter of a function "Onclick" event :

```
<div id="chapters">
<?php
   $array = range(1,20);
   foreach($array as $chapter) {
?>
    <p class="getChapter" onClick="getChapter(<?php echo $chapter;?>)">Chapter <?php echo $chapter;?></p>
<?php
   }
?>
```

and the Javascript:

```
function getChapter(chapterNumber) {
    alert(chapterNumber);
}
```

Comment: The output from getChapter() somehow is always undefined

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer. please test again with the new code.

Comment: You are welcome! If my code helped you please upvote it and mark it as the answer so it would help others too :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do, seems you explanation just a example, but may be this will help. You can call function  **getChapter** with parameter (  **onClick="getChapter(<?php echo $chapter;?>)** ) :

```
$array = range(1,20);
    foreach($array as $chapter) {
    ?>
        <p class="getChapter" id="currChapter" onClick="getChapter(<?php echo $chapter;?>)">Chapter <?php echo $chapter;?></p>
    <?php
    }


function getChapter(chapter) {
    document.write(chapter);
}
```

Comment: This is still wrong, `id`s within the document are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Yes, I took out the id